# Problem with overlapping image and text HTML with Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a problem with HTML... I need to overlap two lines of text with an image. I am working with bootstrap4 and I am working with a template and in this code, the template works very well:

```
<section class="position-relative dark-overlay py-3 py-lg-7 overflow-hidden" data-parallax="scroll" data-image-src="img/photo/erii-gutierrez-487083-unsplash.jpg" data-speed="0.3" data-position-x="right">
      <div class="container overlay-content hero hero-page">
        <ul class="breadcrumb justify-content-center no-border mb-0">
          <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a class="text-white" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
          <li class="breadcrumb-item text-white active">Ladies</li>
        </ul>
        <div class="hero-content pb-5 text-center text-white">
          <h1 class="hero-heading">Ladies</h1><p class="lead">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

And this is what Im trying and I don't know why it doesn't work

```
<section class="dark-overlay overflow-hidden" data-parallax="scroll" style="width:100%">
   <div class="position-relative container overlay-content hero hero-page">
            <img src="img/fotos/cava720.gif" width="100%">

     <div class="hero-content text-center text-white">
       <h1 class="hero-heading">Title</h1><p class="lead">subtitle</p>
     </div>
   </div>
</section>
```

Do you know what's happening?

All I know is that in the template there is some JavaScript code that i don't really understand...

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways of having text cover an image and it currently looks like your hero content is coming after your image. I usually solve this by putting the text in a div and then making the image the background for the div.

Here is the CSS and  HTML:

```css
.container{
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b6/Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png/1200px-Image_created_with_a_mobile_phone.png");
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hero-content text-center text-white">
    <h1 class="hero-heading">Title</h1>
    <p class="lead">subtitle</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see it in a [codepen here](https://codepen.io/danhebdon/pen/bGqVXbE)

and you can read about the customisation of the background property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp)